# How do I make a div triangle with concave left border?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make [this shape](http://leonsdiego.com/images/how_n2.png) in CSS. I haven´t been able to get it perfectly.

Comment: Show your code, till now what have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, I have done with the `:before` pseudo class. We can tweak the below snippet to make it look like what you need:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
}

.triangle:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 3px;
  top: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Another try:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
}

.triangle:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 110px;
  left: -90px;
  top: -30px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent snippets. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies soley on CSS generated content, meaning no extra markup. The only caveat, is that `::after` background color must match parent element background color.

```
div::before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 50px 0 50px 100px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}

div::after{
content:'';
display:block;
width:50px;
background:#fff;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
border-radius:0 100% 100% 0;
transform: scaleX(0.4);
transform-origin:top left;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/joyugatiqa)